# Turn an array of numbers into a string of all those numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods, reduce

I'm currently practicing the `.reduce` method in JavaScript and I have to turn an array of numbers into a string of all those numbers using the method mentioned before.

```js
function stringConcat(arr) {
  return arr.reduce((acc, el) => acc.toString(el));
}

console.log(stringConcat([1, 2, 3])); // expected result is "123"
```

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for reduce? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce not sure what you expect `acc.toString(el)` to be doing. The toString() method has no arguments https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toString

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

The idea is to concat `acc` with `el` in every iteration, here is an example for [1,2,3]:

```
iteration 1: acc = '', el = 1 return '1'
iteration 2: acc = '1', el = 2 return '12'
iteration 3: acc = '12', el = 3 return '123'
```

```js
function stringConcat(arr) {

  return arr.reduce((acc, el) => `${acc}${el}`);

}
console.log(stringConcat([1,2,3])); // the expected result is "123"
```

Learn more about [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Cheers!